# ReactJS properties validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm moving from ReactJs to React-Native and found this function structure [in facebook's code for a react-native button](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js):

```
class Button extends React.Component<{
  title: string,
  onPress: () => any,
  color?: ?string,
  hasTVPreferredFocus?: ?boolean,
  accessibilityLabel?: ?string,
  disabled?: ?boolean,
  testID?: ?string,
}> {
  static propTypes = {
    /**
     * Text to display inside the button
     */
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    /**
     * Text to display for blindness accessibility features
     */
    accessibilityLabel: PropTypes.string,
    /**
     * Color of the text (iOS), or background color of the button (Android)
     */
    color: ColorPropType,
    /**
     * If true, disable all interactions for this component.
     */
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    /**
     * TV preferred focus (see documentation for the View component).
     */
    hasTVPreferredFocus: PropTypes.bool,
    /**
     * Handler to be called when the user taps the button
     */
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    /**
     * Used to locate this view in end-to-end tests.
     */
    testID: PropTypes.string,
  };

  ...
}
```

In ReactJS I used just to build my components with `propTypes` checking, so:

a) What is the purpose of having the props specification inside the brackets at the class definition (<{...}> ? Is this available also in normal ReactJS?

b)  Will that check the passed properties format? If so, why do I need propTypes here?

Answer (score 4):

For clarity's sake, the proper term for the definition inside the brackets is called a generic, which is like a type argument when the function/class/whatever is unsure what the type of something is, so it lets you fill in the blanks - in this case, the type for the component's props.

Particularly, this syntax looks like [Flow](https://flow.org), but [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org) is also a popular option for type checking.

So:

- The generic is used to type check using your component at compile time. This is syntax specific to type checkers, and isn't available in normal JS.
- `propTypes` is used to check the types during runtime, to improve DX for people who aren't using a type system.

Generally, projects with type systems only opt to use the generic to reduce verbosity, If you're using a type system, `propTypes` is only really needed if you're releasing the component to the public.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook uses [Flow](https://flow.org) (you can see comments on top of the source code) for static analysis. You can use Typescript or any other analyzer. Main goal of defining `props` types is to prevent programming mistakes. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

React component takes 2 generic [parameters](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L281) `React.Component<PropType, context> {}`.

1. Prop types
2. Context

Also React.Component has some static properties like

1. `propTypes` which defines what are the props this component can take.
2. `defaultProps` defines default values of the props if they are not passed from the parent.

Coming to your question:

> What is the purpose of having the props specification inside the
>   brackets at the class definition <{...}>?

To define what are the props the component can take, for static analysis and error reporting for required props if they are not passed.

> Is this available also in normal ReactJS?

Yes (You'll have to add Flow or TypeScript to your project)

> Will that check the passed properties format.  If so, why do I need propTypes here??

Yes, some times where the type of the props can't be inferred at compile time, then it would be useful to see any warnings generated from using `propTypes`. [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application)