# What is the difference between these 2 ways to create a functional component with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I search to unsderstand the difference between this 2 functional components:

```
interface SquareProps {
  cote: string;
  text: string;
  bgc: string;
}

const SquareA: React.FC<SquareProps> = (props) => {...}
```

and

```
const SquareB: = (props: SquareProps) => {...}
```

What is the difference between using the first solution or the second?

Comment: None of those are hooks. These are just functional components. The first example additionally tells the compiler that the function is actually a functional component rather than a usual function. Except from this they are pretty much the same.

Comment: i thinks those are same.

Comment: @trixn edited the question so it's more clear.

Comment: You may refer to this too! There are some answers to your question on the answers and comments on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931632/whats-the-proper-way-of-giving-react-stateless-functional-component-a-typescrip/57932224#57932224

Comment: I use hook in the fonction i juste want understand the différence between 2 way in exemple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best™ way is to use `React.FC` when typing functional components.

It gives typescript type hints about special properties like `defaultProps` and `displayName` and adds the correct types to props like `children`.

Both ways create valid functional components but the first one is more accurately typed making it less likely to be misused and provide better code completion.

Comment: I have hide the code between {...} But i use hook in the fonction.

Comment: @A.Vincent Okay so as it seems to be irrelevant I removed it from my answer.