# Is there way to use PropTypes along with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I'm migrating my React project to TS and in component (I deleted most of props to simplify code):

```
interface Props {
  activeTabIdx: number;
  setActiveTab: Function;
}

const HeaderTabs = ({ activeTabIdx, setActiveTab}: Props) => {
  ...
};

HeaderTabs.propTypes = {
  activeTabIdx: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  setActiveTab: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  activeTabIdx: state.tabs.activeValue,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setActiveTab: _setActiveTab,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HeaderTabs);
```

On last line appears error:

```
Argument of type '{ ({ visible, className, activeTabIdx, setActiveTab, values }: Props): JSX.Element | null; propTypes: { values: PropTypes.Validator<any[]>; activeTabIdx: PropTypes.Validator<number>; setActiveTab: PropTypes.Validator<...>; visible: PropTypes.Validator<...>; className: PropTypes.Requireable<...>; }; defaultProps: { ....' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
```

And when I delete `PropTypes` usage this error disappeares. So what can I do to make TS and PropTypes work together?

**PS. I really want to remain usage of PropTypes because it can detect errors in runtime**

Comment: That'd be redundant. You don't need prop-types if you're using typescript.

Comment: PS. I really want to remain usage of PropTypes because it can detect errors in runtime (for example when API changes contract)

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict between the type in proptypes and the type in typescript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PropTypes in a TypeScript React Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application)

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a conflict between how you specify types in proptype and typescript in your code.