# Proptypes in React with Typescript component throw error TS 2322

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with TypeScript on React, plus I'm validating props on runtime with PropTypes. 
Recently I updated to TypeScript 3.9.3 and since then things are breaking.
Given this interface:

```
interface StoryQuestionsProps extends WithMediaProps {
  questionObject: {
    question: string,
    answer: string,
    nid?: string,
    path?: string,
    type?: string,
  },
  children?: JSX.Element | string,
}
```

If I declare these PropTypes:

```
StoryQuestions.propTypes = {
  questionObject: PropTypes.shape({
    question: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    answer: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    nid: PropTypes.string,
    path: PropTypes.string,
    type: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.element,
    PropTypes.string,
  ]),
}
```

Throws error TS2322:

> Type 'Validator; answer: Validator; nid: Requireable; path: Requireable; type: Requireable; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<{ question: string; answer: string; nid?: string | undefined; path?: string | undefined; type?: string | undefined; }>'.   Type 'InferProps<{ question: Validator; answer: Validator; nid: Requireable; path: Requireable; type: Requireable; }>' is not assignable to type '{ question: string; answer: string; nid?: string | undefined; path?: string | undefined; type?: string | undefined; }'.     Types of property 'nid' are incompatible.       Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.         Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Instead, expecting any type:

```
StoryQuestions.propTypes = {
  questionObject: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.element,
    PropTypes.string,
  ]),
}
```

it doesn't return errors, but this way I would miss the `questionObject` properties validation. Why `propType.shape()` is not working?
I've also tried wrapping `propTypes.shape()` with `propTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.shape( ... ))` but has no effect.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the Typescript code is a component library which is imported in plain javascript files. By my previous reads, PropTypes are still necessary and removing them may be not be a good a idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43187969

Comment: I ran into the same issue with a nullable boolean prop inside `PropTypes.shape()` and was able to resolve it with `PropTypes.oneOf([true, false, undefined]).isRequired` instead of `PropTypes.bool`.  I'm not sure if you can adapt that to a string but I discovered this question while searching for my issue.  Strings worked fine for me in TS, mine look exactly as you have your laid out

Answer (score -1):

While `propTypes` are an excellent tool, there is no need to use `propTypes` when you are working with TypeScript and React. You can simply replace the `propTypes` with interfaces or type aliases for your component's props.

Once you have defined the interfaces, you can safely remove the `propTypes` from your components. You may want to do it incrementally and test it out properly in case you break anything.

That being said, I do not see any issues with the way `StoryQuestionsProps` is defined.

Comment: It’s a legacy project, and removing PropTypes while would make sense for the reasons you said, is not a viable solution.

Comment: Actually `propTypes` provides runtime validation for the props to catch any differences between compile-time and runtime types, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690878/323177 for more details

Comment: >  there is no need to use propTypes when you are working with TypeScript and React

That's not strictly true if you're building a library. Consumers may not be using TS, but you still want to provide type validation

Comment: An example situation where this is still required would be if you're api sent a string instead of a number. Typescript wont catch this but the proptypes check will.