# How to use Typescript Union Type in React PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, create-react-app, react-proptypes

I am trying to do something like that:

```js
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
  country: 'ONE' | 'OTHER;
}
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  country: PropTypes.oneOf(['ONE', 'OTHER']).isRequired,
};
```

And I am receiving this error:

```
Type 'Validator<string>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<"ONE" | "OTHER">'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ONE" | "OTHER"'.ts(2322)
```

Two doubts:

1. How can I type it using PropTypes?
2. There is a simpler way to work with both Typescript and PropTypes in a TypeScript Create React APP application?

Comment: Why are you using proptypes at the same time with Typescript?

Comment: @GuyIncognito they not contradict, you can and sometimes should use them both.

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, there's no need for PropTypes.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use both. If you're working on a library, the consumers of your code may be using JavaScript — and PropTypes is the only way for them to validate their props. Also, PropTypes can detect excess properties that cause wasted renders.

Answer (score 8):

Narrow the type from `string[]` to `['ONE', 'OTHER']` using a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  country: PropTypes.oneOf(['ONE', 'OTHER'] as const).isRequired,
};
```

Comment: this should be noted in the official docs of propTypes! hours!

Answer (score 0):

When working with Typescript, there are tools for converting types to their `PropTypes` equiviliants.

Tools like:

- [`babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes`](https://github.com/milesj/babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes#readme)
- [`prop-types-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/prop-types-ts)

For anyone who wonders why you should use PropTypes with Typescript, [read here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690878/7882470)