# Should I still use PropTypes if I use Typescript in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-proptypes

Typesscript adds a lot for validating types.

Does it eliminate the need for using PropTypes?

Or do PropTypes still add value in some way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application#:~:text=Typescript%20and%20PropTypes%20serve%20different,autocomplete%20for%20function%20calls%2C%20etc.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between them are that `TS` checks at compile time and `PropTypes` at runtime. If you want to be safer you can compile `TS` to `PropTypes` with https://github.com/milesj/babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes, in this case, you will have both of them but will write types only once.