# TypeScript error on an ErrorBoundary component connected with Redux (mapStateToProps)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-typescript, react-error-boundary

I'm facing a type issue on an React/ErrorBoundary component, stating that *Argument of type 'typeof ErrorBoundary' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<* ***never*** *>'*.

[image: Error - Argument of type 'typeof ErrorBoundary' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.]

Just to clarify: I use mapStateToProps to connect it with user's language preferences set on store.

Here's my component

```
interface ErrorTexts {
  texts: ErrorTextType;
}

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
  texts: ErrorTextType;
}

interface State {
  error: Error | null;
}

class ErrorBoundary extends Component<Props, State> {
  static propTypes = {
    children: node,
    texts: errorTextsPropType
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    children: null,
    texts: defaultTexts.en.error
  };

  state: State = {
    error: null
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error): State {
    return { error };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
    console.error('Something unexpected had happened', error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    const { error }: { error: Error | null } = this.state;
    const { texts }: ErrorTexts = this.props;

    if (error) {
      return <ErrorComponent error={error.message} texts={texts} />;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): ErrorTexts => ({
  texts: state.texts.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ErrorBoundary);
```

For reference, these are my imported ErrorText types:

```
export interface ErrorTextType {
  errorLine1: string;
  errorLine2: string;
  notifyMe: string;
  title: string;
}

export const errorTextsPropType = shape({
  errorLine1: string.isRequired,
  errorLine2: string.isRequired,
  notifyMe: string.isRequired,
  title: string.isRequired
});
```

Accordinly, on the mother component, I've got an error *This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type '***never***', but multiple children were provided.*

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? :/

Comment: Remove `static propTypes`. You are already using TypeScript, So you don't need `propTypes` for type checking. Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Comment: @ajeet-shah I guess I have to disagree with that. PropTypes here help me with my props on runtime. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690878/10264581), TypeScript and PropTypes have different purposes on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the interface `Props` separately, use `InferProps` generic to infer the prop type:

```
import PropTypes, { shape, InferProps} from "prop-types";

class ErrorBoundary extends Component<InferProps<typeof ErrorBoundary.propTypes>, State> {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    texts: errorTextsPropType,
  };
```