# React TypeScript, How to fix typing issues when using "mui-icons" as props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have small project compost by only a `App.JSX` that works 100%, but I need to turn it in to `App.TSX`.

When I change the extension to `.TSX`, I get two errors, I don't know how to deal with them.

1. `function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {`. This one seems to be fixed by adding a `:any` at the end of `props`.

```
(parameter) props: any
Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

2. `DoneIcon` in `<MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={DoneIcon} />` I don't have any idea how to deal with this one.

```
(alias) const DoneIcon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & {
    muiName: string;
}
import DoneIcon
Demos:

Icons
Material Icons
API:

SvgIcon API
Type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactElementLike | null | undefined'.
  Type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElementLike': type, props, keyts(2322)
App.tsx(21, 47): Did you mean to call this expression?
```

Small and full project file:

```js
import DoneIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Done";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const StatusImage = props.statusImage;
  return (
    <div>
      <StatusImage />
    </div>
  );
}

MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element,
};

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={DoneIcon} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you include the full error text?

Comment: @Diesel Is this better?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Typescript.

your first error states `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any'` and this is true. You can explicitly declare it as `any`, but then why use Typescript? `unknown` is almost always better than `any` because if you know the type then declare it. If you don't, then it is unknown. I only use `any` when I just don't have the time and recognize what I lose by doing it. Below is a template you can use.

```
type TypeName = {
  text: string;
};

const ComponentName: React.FC<TypeName> = ({ text }) => {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
};
```

Your second error is pointing out that `DoneIcon` which is of the type `'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }'` cannot be assigned to the type `statusImage` requires which is `ReactElementLike`. So you need to figure out how to make DoneIcon fit the type of `ReactElementLike` which requires the properties `type`, `props`, and `key`.

This is all from "@types/prop-types" and the `PropTypes` you are using. I personally do not use them. PropTypes and Typescript types are not the same thing, one is checked at runtime, the other at compile time. [If you have access to `MyComponentWithIconProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application) then I would get rid of `PropTypes` and all the type definitions imported for them. I think this will simplify your types. If I could see `MyComponentWithIconProps` I would recommend a change. But for now I'd recommend getting rid of

```
MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element,
};
```

and properly declaring the `statusImage` type in `MyComponentWithIconProps` (or temporarily using `any` to get up and running)`