# Looking for a method to display the props and types of a custom component in a table

Tags: typescript, types

I am building a documentation website for a custom design system and I am trying to create a table that displays the props of each component. The functional component table takes any component and outputs a table with the props, types..etc. I am struggling to find a way to do that for the props and types. My goal is to have something close to storybook args, but without using storybook.

example :

## Output

| Prop | type |
| --- | --- |
| variant | buttonvariant |
| onclick | function |

Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tbh I tried iterating over the type but I realized it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Types exist only at compile time, so all traces of the props and their types are removed from your code when it's executing.

For example, this:

```
interface MyComponentProps { abc: number }
function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps) {
  return <div>test</div>
}
```

Compiles to:

```
"use strict";
function MyComponent(props) {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "test");
}
```

So the props names and their types are *completely absent* in this output.

---

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690878/62076) has some resources about creating [React PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) from your typescript types during the compilation of your code to javascript. This creates runtime version of your prop types that you could then theoretically iterate over in a react component to visualize it.

Comment: Thanks ill check out out! great explanation also.