# Is there any way to generate typescript types for React component props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Before moving to Typescript I was using [react-proptypes-generate](https://github.com/dpzxsm/react-proptypes-generate) extension for VS Code, this saved me ton of time, it is so time-consuming to type props manually by hand, to make matters worse if you are using external libraries finding correct types is also time-consuming.

Is there any way to automate generation of **typescript types for props** in Typescript (at least partially) or to infer them automatically?

Edit :

To be clear, I am not trying to migrate from prop types to typescript, I have already removed the old proptypes from the code when moving to TS, what I want is way to auto generate **typescript types for props**?

Comment: Maybe you can combine that with Prince Kumar's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application#:~:text=Typescript%20and%20PropTypes%20serve%20different,autocomplete%20for%20function%20calls%2C%20etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PropTypes in a TypeScript React Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application)

Comment: @Rami16 sorry for the confusion, I am not trying to migrate existing prop types to ts, but to generate typescript types for props? I updated the question to be more clear. Most annoying problem with manually typing types is using external libraries like MUI, there are so much complex types wrapping one another.