# How declare a type with PropType?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I want to declare a React.CssProperties prop to my component, but utilizing PropTypes. So far, I can make it works with `PropTypes.object`. But then when I use the component, I cannot get css property type hint (ex. style like width, color, etc). Also, I have to manually cast it to React.CssProperties when assigning the prop to element.

Is there a way to declare a type like React.CssProperties with PropeTypes in Typescript?

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes, {InferProps} from "prop-types";

const propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string,  
  style: PropTypes.object,
};
type Props = InferProps<typeof propTypes>;

const MyButton = ({text, style}:  Props) => {
  return (
    <button style={style as React.CSSProperties} />
  )
})
```

```js
import React from 'react';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyButton style={{width: '100px'}}>{text}</button> // no type hint in IDE when typing width, color..etc
  )
}
export App
```

Comment: I just wondering. Why would you need prop types when you already have TypeScript?

Comment: Some said they are different.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application. Typescript validates types at compile time, whereas PropTypes are checked at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the optimize code:

```
import { CSSProperties, FC } from 'react';

interface MyButtonProps {
  text: string;
  style?: CSSProperties;
}

const MyButton: FC<MyButtonProps> = ({ text, style }) => {
  return (
    <button style={style}>{text}</button>
  );
};

export default MyButton;
```

Here is the result:
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: @Arst Let me know if still face any issue or doubts?

Comment: My questions is about using PropTypes from 'prop-types' as the props definition...

Comment: Hi, You can achieve this without PropTypes from `prop-types`. Let me know if you want to achieve with `prop-types`, I'll share with this also.

Comment: If you have doubts related to which DataType is suitable in your case, checkout this blog: [proptypes vs types](https://medium.com/smallcase-engineering/proptypes-vs-types-in-typescript-45433990a8f9)

Answer (score 0):

you not need to import propTypes from propTypes. simply use type

```js
import React from 'react';


type PropTypes = {
  text: string,  
  style: any,
};

const MyButton = ({text, style}:  Props) => {
  return (
    <button style={style as React.CSSProperties} />
  )
})
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Your answer is not correct, I'm sharing why:

Comment: - style prop is defined as any, which is not ideal.

Comment: - PropTypes is defined but is not being used later on.